# Solving $y'' + n^2 y = 0 $ with boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I'm trying to solve the following

$$y'' + n^2 y = 0$$ with $y(0)=y(H) = 0$

This should return $y(x) = \sin(2n\pi * x/H)$

However, in MATLAB it simply returns zero.

My code is

```
syms y(x) H n 

ode2 = diff(y,x,2) + n^2*y == 0 ;


 cond1 = y(0) == 0 ;


 cond2 = y(H) == 0 ;

 cond = [cond1 cond2];

 dsolve(ode2, cond)
```

This seems like a simple enough problem to solve, I just odn't know where I'm going wrong. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your $y(x)$ is just a constant, so $y''=0$ and $n^2y=n^2\sin(2\pi n/H)$. The particular solution here is $y=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I missed x out of the sine. The is y=0 for n=0. For n=/=0 it's not. But MATLAB won't seem to compute the solution for n=/= 0

Comment: The general solution is $y=c_1\cos(nx)+c_2\sin(nx)$, so $y(0)=0$ forces $c_1=0$, and $y(H)=0$ forces $c_2\sin(nH)=0$. If $\sin(nH)\neq 0$, then you get a nontrivial solution, but MatLab probably needs to be fed that assumption.

Comment: Yeah exactly I just don't know how to enforce this

Comment: Please do not cross-post. At least mark the cross-posts as such.

Comment: How to get Matlab to do something?  Hardly a topic for this forum.

Comment: alright mate cool off

Comment: Check your boundary conditions.